# How do i construct a code for this problem?

Tags: logic, pattern-recognition

In a village there are n houses , some have electricity some dont. Those having electricity are labeled as 1 and others 0.

Houses are arranged in a line from left to right (1 to n).

let x1 x2 x3..... be coordinates of the houses.(1= < x1< x2< x3...)

The houses having electricity are to be connected with those which don't have.

What is the minimum length of wire required so that all houses have electricity??

Example:No. of houses n=3

Label 100

coordinates 1,5,6

Minimum length req= 6-1=5 (connect first and third house. The wire will go through 2nd house thus all have electricity)

2)label 10100

coordinates 1,4,6,9,88

Minimum length = 84=[(6-4)+(88-6)]